# Nuxt 3 | Cannot use api on deployed Firestore hosting website

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project that runs with no issues on localhost.
However, when it is deployed to Firestore hosting, all of the fetch('api/') fails with error.

Deployed as below:

```
% NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4096" yarn generate
% firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Error example:

```
GET https://<site name>/api/videos?onAir=1&limit=20 404
```

Api response:

```
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'https://<site name>/api/videos?future=1&limit=6', redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
true
headers
: 
Headers {}
ok
: 
false
redirected
: 
false
status
: 
404
statusText
: 
""
type
: 
"basic"
url
: 
"https://<site name>/api/videos?future=1&limit=6"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Response
```

.output file looks like this.
[image]

APIs are located in server/api folder.
[image]

How can I use my api on the deployed website?
Am I doing it completely wrong?

**Edit:**
api response on yarn start. It seems succeeding, but it is not expected response.

```
Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/videos?future=1&limit=6', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body
: 
(...)
bodyUsed
: 
true
headers
: 
Headers
[[Prototype]]
: 
Headers
ok
: 
true
redirected
: 
false
status
: 
200
statusText
: 
"OK"
type
: 
"basic"
url
: 
"http://localhost:3000/api/videos?future=1&limit=6"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Response
```

Expected response should contains array of requested datas.
(I can get expected response when I try with yarn dev)

Comment: Does it work when bundled and run locally?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge. How can I check that?

Comment: Use `yarn build` or `yarn generate`, then `yarn start` and check if it works locally.

Comment: Thank you for the guide. yarn start caused errors at similar place, but the api response are succeeding.

Comment: What error exactly? Where is it coming from (code wise)?

Comment: It is decoding error caused by the unexpected format of the response: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON